# Pass php variable to angular

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs

I'm using angular to add comments to a list. This is working fine. But I'm stuck with adding a php variable to save this to my list.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12" ng-controller="customerCommentController" ng-init="userInit('<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>')" >
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-header">
            <h3 class="box-title"><?php echo $lang['LBL_CUSTOMER_COMMENTS']; ?></h3>
        </div><!-- /.box-header -->
        <div class="box-body">
            <div ng-include src="'php/layout_customer_comments.php'"</div>
        </div><!-- /.box-body -->
    </div><!-- /.box -->
</div><!-- /.col -->
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('customerCommentApp', []);

app.controller('customerCommentController', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.userInit = function(uid) {
        $scope.user = uid;
    };

    getItem(); 

    function getItem() {
        $http.post("php/getCustomerComment.php").success(function(data){
            $scope.items = data;
        });
    };

    $scope.addItem = function (item) {
        $http.post("php/addCustomerComment.php?item="+item+"&customerId="+$scope.user).success(function(data){
            getItem();
            $scope.itemInput = "";
        });
    };

});
```

I want the "ID" to be saved in my mysql as well. But I dont get it to work.

EDIT:
I've got it to work. Code was ok, but my addCustomerComment.php was not.
But another problem occurs. When opening the page the ID is not passed onto the angular. Only when I click the add button. So a new comment is added to the correct ID, but older comments are only visible after adding a new comment.
How can I get the ID in angular when the page loads?

JS:

```
$scope.userInit = function(uid) {
    $scope.user = uid;
    //$scope.user = '99999';
    };

    // Load all available items
    getItem();  
    function getItem(){  
    $http.post("php/getCustomerComment.php?customerId="+$scope.user).success(function(data){
        $scope.items = data;
       });
    };
```

Comment: This is not the way to proceed. Data should come from the server in an API, even "currentLoggedUser". In a normal app flow, you are not allowed to view anything unless you login - and then you'd already have the loggedUser and that won't be a problem. 

I would suggest simulating a live app and just do a 10-liner login.

Comment: @DragosRusu The ID is not the loggedUser, it is the selected user in a list. Is it not possible to make it work this way? (Or just not the recommended way to do this)

Comment: The selected element on page load?

Comment: @DragosRusu the page url will be www.mydom.com/customer.php?id=10072

Comment: So just use the $routeParams['id'] if you are using routes, or $location.search().id and make that available on the $scope for the template

Answer (score 0):

Try to post your data like this

```
 $scope.createBook = function(book_form,user){

    if(book_form.$invalid) {
        $scope.invalidSubmitAttempt = true;
        return;
    }else{

         $http.post(appurl+'user/adds/', user).success(function() {

});

             $scope.book_form.$setPristine();

         });

 }
}
```